# WPF Creating types of Tabitems in tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

i need to create types of Tabitems to my tabcontrol.
each tab will have different content and functionalities (Xaml and code-behind).
For Example, i want to create:
* Customer details tab - with fields of customer detials.
* Configuration tab - fields for configuring the application.
* Statistics tab - table and graphs with statistics.

Sometimes two or three tabs of each tabitem type will be open.
i don't want to copy paste the TabItem.Content again and again for same customer tab or other.
i want to make a type of tab.

what is the best way to create such tabitem types ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I store my `TabItemViewModels` in a `ParentViewModel`, and use a `DataTemplate` to define how each ViewModel should be displayed.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomerDetailsViewModel}">
        <local:CustomerDetailsView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfigurationViewModel}">
        <local:ConfigurationView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StatisticsViewModel}">
        <local:StatisticsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}" />
```